# C# - Batch encrypt files one by one on Windows, what is the easiest/most secure solution for AES

Tags: c#, encryption, cloud, truecrypt

I am not good at cryptography.
I want to batch encrypt files one by one on Windows.
I was going to use truecrypt 7.1a as I trust it, until I found it has no command line support on windows and the only way to do it is to use hacky scripting languages to work out the process simulating user action on UI (AutoIt or similar).

I see there is openssl commands to do that and maybe PGP.

The idea is to encrypt files one by one to keep them on the cloud and be able to use them with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.edslite&hl=it)

I want to encrypt files one by one and not bundled togheter in one volume.

You know which is better and can provide related code? I Don't know which one to choose.

Any other app/solution or system to keep files encrypted on cloud and clever implementation is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/), which is a fork of TrueCrypt, supports command line parameters for the whole set of features. That's what I needed.